# jquery not sending data to Post Action Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, viewmodel

I am trying to save a ViewModel object from a partial view in a modal, and I get a 404 error when I try to post it. The url is being called, but the ViewModel data isn't being sent. I have been reading similar questions on here and on MSN for hours and nothing I've tried fixes the problem. I took out the repetitive days of the week code for brevity, but I can
add them back in if anyone wants a complete working example. Here is the code

**EmployeeViewModel**

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public bool Monday { get; set; } = false;
        //...bool properties for Tuesday through Sunday
        public Employee Employee { get; set; } 
    }
```

**Employee/ _AddEmployeeModalPartial**

```
@model JSarad_C868_Capstone.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="modal modal-fade" id="addEmployee">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="addEmpoyeeLabel">Add Employee</h4>
                <button type=button class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>x</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="Add">
                   
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input asp-for="Employee.Id" class="form-control" />
                        <input asp-for="Employee.Availability" class="form-control" />
                        <label asp-for="Employee.Role"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Employee.Role" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Bartender">Bartender</option>
                            <option value="Server">Server</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Employee.Role" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    
                    @*<div class="mb-3">*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Employee.Name"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Employee.Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Employee.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    
                   @* <div class="mb-3">*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Employee.Phone"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Employee.Phone" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Employee.Phone" class="text-danger"> 
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    
                    @*<div class="mb-3">*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Employee.Email"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Employee.Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Employee.Email" class="text-danger"> 
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    
                    @*<div class="mb-3">*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Employee.Address"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Employee.Address" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Employee.Address" class="text-danger"> 
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    
                   @* <div class="mb-3">*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Availabiliy</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row pb-4">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input asp-for="Monday" class="form-check-input" 
                                       type="checkbox" />
                                <label asp-for="Monday" class="form-check-label"></label>
                            </div>
                            <!--...//form check boxes for Tuesday trough Sunday -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
                        data-bs-save="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EmployeeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Add()
{
    EmployeeViewModel viewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
    return PartialView("_AddEmployeeModalPartial", viewModel); ;
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Add(EmployeeViewModel viewModel) //code never reaches this Action
{
    viewModel.Employee.Availability = ConvertDaysToChar(viewModel.Employee.Availability)
    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Employees.Add(viewModel.Employee);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_AddEmployeeModelPartial", viewModel);
    }
}
```

site.js

```
$(function () {
    var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
    $('button[data-bs-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
       /* event.preventDefault();*/
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        console.log(url)
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');

        })
    })
    PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-bs-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        console.log(actionUrl);
        var sendViewModel = form.serialize();
        console.log(sendViewModel);
        
        //$.post(actionUrl, sendViewModel).done(function (data) {
        //    PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
        /*above is the code from a tutorial for modals. It also doesn't send the object to 
         post action*/
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: actionUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(sendViewModel),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

When I click the save button on the model, the **console.log(sendViewModel)** returns the correct Serialization with all of the properties and their correct names. And the properties change correctly when there is input.

```
Employee.Id=&Employee.Availability=&Employee.Role=Bartender&Employee.Name=&Employee.Phone=&Employee.Email=&Employee.Address=&Monday=false&Tuesday=false&Wednesday=false&Thursday=false&Friday=false&Saturday=false&Sunday=false
```

But I get an error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
and when I check it the page says "No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44313/Add  HTTP ERROR 404" as if it's trying to get a post. It is also missing the controller, but if I change my form action to "Employee/Add" in the _Partial view it still doesn't send the data along with the url, which is causing an entirely different problem. I would greatly appreciate any help or guess or input of any kind. I'm about five seconds away from throwing my laptop out the window on this one. Thanks.

Comment: `https://localhost:44313/Add` isnt' it the incorrect URL? it should be `https://localhost:44313/Employee/Add`

Comment: The second one, but even when I change my form action to action="/Employee/Add" or "Employee/Add" or any variation, it just gives me an error and when I open it it is trying to direct me to the [HttpGet] Employee Add. Basically, there is no view model passed as a parameter.

Comment: Also, when I make that change my 404 error goes away and I have a 400 error instead.

Comment: 400 error is Syntax error for client request. Check your data.

Comment: Have a try :change " dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json', data: JSON.stringify(sendViewModel)," into "contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', data: sendViewModel,"

Comment: There is no data to check. That's the problem. The data is not being sent to the controller. And it is definitely not formed properly, but I don't know how to fix it. when I check the value of JSON.stringify(sendViewModel); it is exactly the same as the serialized model. "Employee.Id=&Employee.Availability=&Employee.Role=Bartender&Employee.Name=&Employee.Phone=&Employee.Email=&Employee.Address=&Monday=false&Tuesday=false&Wednesday=false&Thursday=false&Friday=false&Saturday=false&Sunday=false", and my Add(EventViewModel viewModel) paramater apparently will not take this format.

Comment: I actually have tried that, but I will try it again now that I have changed the url. Wait, are you sending it with two data parameters?

Comment: @QingGuo, thankyou, but it didn't work. Same problem. No viewmodel is getting sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Remove the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside your form,like below:

```
 <form action="Add"  >
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  ....
```

Then after you serialize the form you can get the AntiForgeryToken, like below:

[image]
Because when you don't add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`inside form, after you serialize the form you don't get the AntiForgeryToken, like below:

[image]

Besides, if you use  `<form asp-action="Add"  >` In ASP.Net Core anti forgery token is automatically added to forms, so you don't need to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`,you can find in the below :

[image]

2.change your ajax like below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',            
            url:'/Employee/Add',            
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: sendViewModel,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Data received: ');
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @user17195990 Please have a look at my answer~ viewmodel is getting sent.

Comment: Awesome. I'm going to try that today. I got the viewmodel sending, but my validation isn't working.

Comment: @user17195990 You can create a new post to describe your problem about validation isn't working, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I had to change the form action from "Add" to "Employee/Add". ThenI had to remove the antiforgery token from my post action. The first code that is commented out actually works fine otherwise. In my defense I did remove the antiforgery token when I had the wrong URL, but I forgot to retest that when I had the correct one.